# Using Cross Browser with cypress

Tags: cypress

i am trying to open Chrome 8 on cypress but I get the default browser electron. Chrome is installed on my device

Erro I get :  **Message:** Can't run because you've entered an invalid browser name.

Browser: 'chrome' was not found on your system.

Available browsers found are: electron

**Stack trace:**

```
[object Object]
    at get (C:\Users\Harryma\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.4.1\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\errors.js:348:11)
    at Object.throwErr [as throw] (C:\Users\Harryma\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.4.1\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\errors.js:363:11)
    at throwBrowserNotFound (C:\Users\Harryma\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.4.1\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\browsers\index.js:141:22)
    at C:\Users\Harryma\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.4.1\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\browsers\index.js:124:12
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
From previous event:
    at fn (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:88749:14)
    at ipcBus (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:88768:10)
    at Object.ipc.<computed> [as openProject] (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:88809:69)
    at Object.openProject (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:91221:67)
    at Project.componentDidMount (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:90805:78)
    at ik (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75383:360)
    at ../../node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.production.min.js.exports.unstable_runWithPriority (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:85486:437)
    at fg (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75252:325)
    at Yj (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75376:437)
    at Lj (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75355:420)
    at file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75253:115
    at ../../node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.production.min.js.exports.unstable_runWithPriority (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:85486:437)
    at fg (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75252:325)
    at ig (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75253:61)
    at jg (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75252:496)
    at bk (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75356:156)
    at reactionScheduler (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:48924:47)
    at runReactions (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:48900:5)
    at endBatch (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:48600:9)
From previous event:
    at App.componentDidMount (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:86770:77)
    at ik (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75383:360)
    at ../../node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.production.min.js.exports.unstable_runWithPriority (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:85486:437)
    at fg (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75252:325)
    at Yj (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75376:437)
    at Lj (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75355:420)
    at Rg (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75346:137)
    at rk (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75411:43)
    at file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75414:301
    at ck (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75356:210)
    at zk (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75414:287)
    at render (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:75418:416)
    at Object.start (file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/app.js:89381:61)
    at file:///C:/Users/Harryma/AppData/Local/Cypress/Cache/4.4.1/Cypress/resources/app/packages/desktop-gui/dist/index.html:29:11
```

Comment: Do you see chrome in cypress test runner? May be try by giving the path; `cypress run --browser /path/to/chrome`

Comment: Please add more details. How are you running Cypress? Is it through the UI using `cypress open` or headless using `cypress run`? If headless please try the suggestion by Amit Verma above. If it's in the UI check the browser list in the top right corner. If that doesn't help please also tell us what you already tried